# Reset BlackBerry-10 Dev Alpha simulator

Tags: blackberry-simulator, blackberry-10

I want to reset my BlackBerry 10 Dev Alpha simulator. Does anybody know how to do it?

I tried "Reset this virtual machine" option from VMware but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By reset, do you mean restart? (VM/Power/Restart Guest)

Or do you mean start with a clean simulator?

Well, you don't need to reset your simulator, just create a new VM!